# TouchSwipe jQuery Plugin navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm messing around with TouchSwipe jQuery plugin. I successfully added a sort of navigation by swiping left (previous article) and right (next article). If i try my snippet of code alone it works, when i put this on my blog page, with other jQuery code, no way to work...i don't have a specific error. One of my first attempt was to put jQuery.noConflict but...it doesn't work. I can not understand where i'm stuck
Any help?
This is the code i've made

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        //Enable swiping...
        $("#test").swipe({
            //Generic swipe handler for all directions
            swipeLeft: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
            },
            swipeRight: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                window.location.href = "http://google.com";
            },
            threshold: 0
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Bro can you tell me how would I install this plugin in my webpage . I dont find any document related to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link i saw this:

```
TypeError: jQuery is undefined
var jQNC = jQuery.noConflict();
```

this mean jQuery is not defined is like not exist, so you have to make you JQNC variable like this:

```
var jQNC = $.noConflict();
```

$ for jquery exist.

Comment: I think no error related to this part of jQuery... you can verify here: http://lucascalvi.it/2014/02/synology-ds214-play-nas-recensione-e-benchmark-wd-western-digital-RED-4TB-ds214play

Comment: There is an error in line 214: var jQNC = jQuery.noConflict();
change with var jQNC = $.noConflict(); and i think will work

Comment: The code you mentioned is related to the Twitter plugin...i temporary removed it but still does not work

Comment: jquery file have to be first to all

Comment: Same thing. ..two errors But no one related to this

Comment: This is not a good news for me....i remove ALL the javascript and jQuery code and it's works...i need to try to find the problem with the removed code

Comment: I've found an incompatibily issue with another jQuery plugin that generates charts...i remove it and now it works